# Number of distinct normalized vectors from the center of a hexagon in a hexagonal grid

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, lattices

Consider an infinite hexagonal grid composed of regular hexagons. Choose any hex to be the origin hex. Let n be a natural number.

Find an expression, in terms of n, for the number of distinct normalized vectors from the center of the origin hex to the center of every hexagon whose distance from the origin (measured in hexagons) is less than or equal to n.

I manually calculated up to n=15:

| n | distinct normalized vectors | increment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 6 | - |
| 2 | 12 | 6 |
| 3 | 24 | 12 |
| 4 | 36 | 12 |
| 5 | 60 | 24 |
| 6 | 72 | 12 |
| 7 | 108 | 36 |
| 8 | 132 | 24 |
| 9 | 168 | 36 |
| 10 | 192 | 24 |
| 11 | 252 | 60 |
| 12 | 276 | 24 |
| 13 | 348 | 72 |
| 14 | 384 | 36 |
| 15 | 432 | 48 |

What I do know:

1. The increment from n to n+1 has to be a multiple of 6, because of the simmetry of the hexagon.
2. The expression has to be less than 3n^2+3n, since this is the formula for the total number of hexagons at a distance n, at most, from the origin hex (in hexagons);
3. When n is prime, the increment from n-1 is 6*(n-1).

Comment: The deltas look to be $f(n)=6\phi(n)$ with a possible correction term at odd multiples of 3; the formula agrees for all $n$ you've shown except for $n=9,15$ where it's off by 1.

Comment: @Steven Stadnicki. This makes sense, as a deformation of the lattice should make this problem equivalent to the analogous one with squares. Then it's essentially like counting primitive (GCD=1) pairs of numbers, up to each $n$.

Comment: That was pretty much my thinking as well — I imagine some careful digging would turn up the origin of the correction term too; I just haven't looked closely yet.

Comment: @Pruthviraj I am sorry, I am new to this, I didn't know posting on both Stackexchange and Overflow was abusing the system. I am not sure where this problem belongs though. I guess since there are more comments here already than there, I should delete the one from Stackexchange?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Thanks guys for the early insights! I see now the increments follow almost exactly 6*Phi(n), except at odd multiples of 3. I would appreciate so much if this could be proved and the source of the discrepancy at odd multiples of 3. This problem arose in an actual project I am working on, where I need to know the results for n up to 50.

Comment: Why not push your calculations further, then? n up to 50 seems like it should be computable in a couple of seconds on a consumer PC. Also, do you have a factor of 2 error? For n=1 the answer is clearly 3 if you're counting lines as opposed to normalised vectors from the origin to the centre of the other hex.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You are right, I misstated the problem. The "lines" I am looking for are actually directed. So, for n=1, the line joining the origin and the northeast hexagon is distinct from the line joining the origin and the southwest hexagon, for example. Do you have a suggestion for how to precisely state the problem? I do not even have a degree in Maths (engineer here), I am just an enthusiast.

Comment: @PeterTaylor As for why don't I calculate up to n=50, the truth is I wouldn't know how to write an algorithm for that! The values I presented up to n=15 I actually counted by hand, tracing lines at a hex grid in my screen. But past that, the lines begin to pass too closely to centers for me to know for sure if it's exactly traversing the center or if it's a tiny bit off.

Comment: @PeterTaylor ok, I looked up the definition of normalized vectors and it seems to be exactly what I am looking for. I changed the description of the problem, substituting "straight lines" for "normalized vectors". I hope my table makes more sense now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: By [my calculations](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxFjUEKwjAQRfc5xV_OaK0NogvBA3gGcVFtKgN1GpJYsKc3DRRnM8zw339TgwusmWxezzGSF-xxYGxxxQZRdP0Y00nQmGPRJWLTjwEKUYRWX45shaPls0GePoyaxIWcvUlumZpcR4odhJfTYoHlDyvfC1gM9cd3bXIU5e0H6b80Z_9ct49IzIWcF3KVcCF9EE2kFU5ZMDilUsX8A08NPyE=&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), the discrepancies at odd multiples of 3 are errors from your method.

Comment: @PeterTaylor Again, you're right! I botched my calculations for n=9 and n=15. Alas, the answer then is an increment of exactly 6*Phi(n) for all n. Thank you very much!

Comment: I'll edit my original post to reflect the correct calculations past n=9. Thanks to Steven Stadnicki and Peter Taylor, it is clear now the answer should be f(n)= 6*[summation (k=1 to n) Phi(k)], where Phi is Euler's Totient Function. I won't dare posting an answer though, as I am not capable of proving this result.

Comment: @GabrielSchweitzer I'll see if I can't put an answer together; I don't think the argument is hard but it _really_ wants an illustration.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, the argument's easy: it pretty much drops out of the code I linked above. There's rotational symmetry of order 6; if you take one sixth of the circle then the hexagon centres included therein form a lattice, the $n$th ring is given by $\{ k v_0 + (n-k)v_1 : 0 \le k < n \}$, and two hexagons induce the same vector if their coordinates in this basis are linearly dependent.

Comment: Reading now the long thread of comments I see the answer was already given. That's why one should not answer  in comments... It risks to waste other answerers' time. Even few minutes matter! :)

Answer (score 2):

Let's  move the centers of the hexagons to the grid $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ by an affine transformation, so that the centers of the hexagons at hexagonal distance less than or equal to $n$ are now represented by the more Cartesian-looking (but uglier) set
$$H_n:=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}: |x|\le n, |y|\le n, |x-y|\le n, \}.$$
We can  partition $H_n$ into the area in the axis, a square on the first quadrant and a square on the third quadrant; a triangle in the second and a triangle in the fourth quadrant. Counting separately the corresponding normalized vectors from each set, we get, for your $H(n)$ for $n\ge1$
$H(n)=4+2A(n)+2B(n)$, where
$$A(n):=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb N_+ \times \mathbb N_+ :  x\le n,  y\le n, (x,y)=1\}$$
is easily seen to be $A(n)=  -1+\sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k)=$ [A18805](https://oeis.org/A018805) , and so is
$$B(n):=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb N_+ \times \mathbb N_+ :  1\le x<y\le n, (x,y)=1\}$$
which is $B(n)=2\sum_{k=1}^n \phi(k)=$ [A15614](https://oeis.org/A015614).
So for $n\le50$ you have

$$6,12,24,36,60,72,108,132,168,192,$$$$252,276,348,384,432,480,576,612,720,
768,$$$$840,900,1032,1080,1200,1272,1380,1452,1620,1668,$$$$1848,1944,2064,
2160,2304,2376,2592,2700,2844,2940,$$$$3180,3252,3504,3624,3768,3900,4176,
4272,4524,4644,4836,4980,5292,$$$$\dots$$

(In particular the first difference is $6\phi(n)$ as was immediately spotted by Steven Stadnicki)

Comment: (Shouldn't $(0,0)$ be counted too, as the 0-distance point from the origin?)